# What is a PR triumph?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In an answer of an interesting question, [*Is mathematical history written by the victors?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445166/is-mathematical-history-written-by-the-victors/446237#446237), professor Paul Garrett wrote:

> Again, "winning" is certainly not a reliable sign of absolute virtue. Could be a PR triumph, luck, etc. In certain arenas "winning" would be a stigma...

What is a PR triumph? By searching online, I'm sure it's not his own invention. But neither wiktionary nor my dictionary give me much clue on this issue. I can't see any reason that PR here could stand for public relation, proportional representation, or Puerto Rico as it usually does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In context "PR" does, in fact, stand for "public relations". The writer is saying that one way a person can win is by successfully manipulating public opinion ("PR triumph"). That is what propagandists (experts in public relations) do.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bernays

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would say that makes a lot of sense, though I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: Sure this is right. In some fields, persuading people you are right is itself proof that you are right; not in mathematics.